Tail of sum being small has non-zero probability
I would like to show the following:
Let $Y_i$ be positive iid r.v. Assume that $\sum_1^{+\infty} Y_i<+\infty$ A.S. Prove that for a fixed $\epsilon> 0,k\in\mathbb{N}$ there  $\exists K\in\mathbb{N},K>k$ such that the event $\left\{\sum_{K+1}^{+\infty}Y_i<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\}$ has non-zero probability .
Intuitively this makes sense. The tails of the sum must be smaller and smaller, if that probability was zero then I could not have A.S convergence in the first place. I am just not sure how to word it mathematically yet. Could someone help me?

Do you mean $< \infty$ instead of $\le \infty$?

@Mike My sincerest apologies, I was carelss and rushed it. The question comes from a proof where this is taken for granted. Apologies once more

For a fixed $\epsilon > 0$, we have
$$\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty Y_i < \infty\} = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \bigcap_{i=k}^\infty \{\sum_{i+1}^\infty Y_i < 1/n\}.$$
If the left-hand side has probability $1$, then for every $n \ge 1$,
$$P\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\bigcap_{i=k}^\infty \{\sum_{i+1}^\infty Y_i < 1/n\} = 1.$$
For this to be true, there must exist $k$ such that
$$P\bigcap_{i=k}^\infty \{\sum_{i+1}^\infty Y_i < 1/n\} > 0$$
and thus for all $i \ge k$,
$$P\{\sum_{i+1}^\infty Y_i < 1/n\} > 0.$$

I do think the first equation could/should be parsed out a bit more though.....
